# Many aws sso-admin commands failing with 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sso

Even though I have full AWS access and able to create stuff within AWS SSO Console, following CLI command fails:

```
aws sso-admin create-account-assignment 
--instance-arn="arn:aws:sso:::instance/ssoins-xxx" 
--target-id="xyz" 
--target-type="AWS_ACCOUNT" 
--permission-set-arn="arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-xxx/ps-qwe" 
--principal-type="GROUP" 
--principal-id="99672ae6a4-5d62c75e-a849-43a5-bd11-87b2f0c6fdf4"
```

For `FailureReason` when describing the request I'm getting:

> Received a 403 status error: User: arn:aws:iam::xyz:user/ivan.aracki.com is not authorized to perform: sso:CreateAccountAssignment on resource: arn:aws:sso:::account/xyz with an explicit deny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in our case this was happening because my User was part of `ForceMFA` group which was denying this request. For some reason it is not denying ec2, s3 or other API calls. Probably sso-admin API is configured differently.

Solution was to follow this [authenticate-mfa-cli AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/) and exporting variables returned in this call:

```
aws sts get-session-token 
--serial-number arn-of-the-mfa-device 
--token-code code-from-token
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error but I had to specify the region:

```
aws sso-admin create-account-assignment \
  --instance-arn "$SSO_INSTANCE_ARN" \
  --target-id "$AWS_INFRA_ACCOUNT_ID" \
  --target-type "AWS_ACCOUNT" \
  --principal-type "GROUP" \
  --principal-id "$SSO_GROUP_ID" \
  --permission-set-arn "$SSO_PERMISSION_SET_ADMIN_ARN" \
  --region eu-west-3 \
  --no-cli-pager
```